# How to get the Hello "Newline" and World in powershell using regex?

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-ise

How to get the Hello “Newline” and World in powershell using regex?

```
Hello
World
```

I have to get the Hello World from a text file. I'm using powershell.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. I don't see what regular expressions have to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$match = get-content -path <path_to_file> | 
    out-string | 
    select-string "hello`r`nworld"

if ( $match ) {
    write-host $match.matches[0].groups[0].value
}
```

We load the file with `get-content` then flatten the array to a single string, in this case by piping to `out-string`. Finally, the RegEx is applied with an embedded CRLF.

If you have PowerShell 3, then I believe you can use `get-content -raw` (which returns a single string) and pipe straight into `select-string`.

My test file:

```
line1
Hello
World
line4
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
```